# Returning 'incorrect' regardless

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

This has been flagged as a duplicate, i was unaware of the issue at the time but I shall take this post down in the next 48 hours, apologies.

I'm currently working on a python *(v3.5.0:374f501f4567)* program that generates a ranom equation using multiplication, addition or subtraction using. The code works perfectly up until the final hurdle. When trying to return if the answer is correct or incorrect I am thoroughly stumped. When I use the following code:

```
import random
from operator import add,sub,mul
x=random.randint(0,10)
y=random.randint(0,10)
eqn=(add, sub, mul)
eqnchoice=random.choice(eqn)
eqnstring={add:'+',sub:'-',mul:'*'}
useranswer=0
def eqngenerator():
    random.seed
    answer=eqnchoice(x,y)
    answer=round(answer,2)
    print("what's the answer to",x,eqnstring[eqnchoice],y,"=?\n")
    useranswer=input("Enter the answer here:")
    if useranswer==answer:
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Incorrect!')

print(eqngenerator())
```

I am faced with the following problem as seen in the screenshots below.

[image: the first image is an incorrect answer returning 'incorrect!']

[image: The second image is a correct answer but, it is also returning 'incorrect!']

I'm befuddled as to why this is, if anyone can help please do.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: A function without an explicit return statement will return a None value. This is why you get the None printed at the end of your program. Since you are calling print within the function, you can do away with the print() around the eqngenerator call on your last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input() will be giving you a string in your useranswer variable. It will need to converted to a number before use, eg a float or an int

```
useranswer = int(input("Enter the answer here:"))
or
useranswer = float(input("Enter the answer here:"))
```

Use int if you know the answer to your calculation will always be an integer

Answer (score 1):

input returns a string, so you need:

```
useranswer=float(input("Enter the answer here:"))
```

it will raise an error if user enter any other value then a number, so you can make:

```
def eqngenerator():
    random.seed
    answer=eqnchoice(x,y)
    answer=round(answer,2)
    print("what's the answer to",x,eqnstring[eqnchoice],y,"=?\n")
    useranswer=input("Enter the answer here:")
    try:
        if useranswer==answer:
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Incorrect!')
```